# Type mismatch error when assigning values to the array

Tags: vba, excel

If the data is colored RED then store it in an array and display it in a MSGBOX. But not able to as I am getting type mismatch error.

```
             Name         Age        Sex

             John         18          m
             Rita         15          f -------> RED   
             Phil         15          m -------> Red
             Letty        15          f --------> Red
             and so on  

Sub msg()
Dim dar() As Variant
Dim j3 As Variant
r3 = Range("a1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
For i3 = 1 To r3
    If (Range("E" & i3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)) = True Then
        j3 = j3 + 1

        ' Getting Error at this line Type Mismatch error
        Set dar(i3) = Range("b" & i3, "f" & i3).Value

        MsgBox x
    End If
Next i3   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lose the **Set** keyword.
`Set x(i3) = Range("b" & i3, "f" & i3).Value` change to 
`x(i3) = Range("b" & i3, "f" & i3).Value`
**Set** keyword is used to assign objects, you are trying to assign value. That's why the error.

### Edit 1

We forgot to initialize the array.

```
Sub msg()
Dim dar() As Variant
Dim j3 As Variant
r3 = Range("a1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
For i3 = 1 To r3
    If (Range("E" & i3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)) = True Then
        ReDim Preserve dar(j3)
        dar(j3) = Range("b" & i3).Value    'beware, that I have changed the dar(i3) to dar(j3)
        j3 = j3 + 1
        MsgBox x
    End If
Next i3

End Sub
```

### Edit 2

```
Sub msg()
Dim dar() As Variant
Dim j3 As Variant

r3 = Range("a1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
For i3 = 2 To r3 'changed to start at row 2, in row 1 there are headers I guess
    If (Range("E" & i3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)) = True Then

        ReDim Preserve dar(j3)
        dar(j3) = Range(Cells(i3, 1), Cells(i3, 6))

        'store the values from this row only into string
        For y = 1 To 6
            If y = 1 Then
                strMessage = dar(j3)(1, y)
            Else
                strMessage = strMessage & " || " & dar(j3)(1, y)
            End If
        Next y

        j3 = j3 + 1

        'store all previous strings one string, with multiple rows
        If j3 = 1 Then
            strMessage2 = strMessage
        Else
            strMessage2 = strMessage2 & Chr(10) & strMessage 'chr(10) is a line break
        End If

    End If
Next i3

If Not IsEmpty(strMessage2) Then
    MsgBox strMessage2, Title:="Red data"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes tried it now getting **Subscript out of range** error

Comment: Sorry    `dar(i3) = Range("b" & i3, "f" & i3).Value`  This is the code

Comment: Maybe because you are assigning more than one value to the array item. Try this if it works `dar(i3) = Range("b" & i3).Value`. You will maybe need a loop to assign other values from different columns into different dar() items. From column "C" to column "F".

Comment: Added **edit 1**. There is still no loop for other columns. Don't know what you want exactly. If you can provide more details, we can solve the whole case.

Comment: Okay what am trying to do is that i have 4 columns of dynamic data. Am tring to get all the data that is marked in RED and to display all the data that i marked in red and finally display every thing in a MSGBOX

Comment: With your **suggestion** and With my previous code  `Range("b" & i3, "f" & i3).Value` There is no Problem in using this code. Only Problem now is to display the data in msgbox. Can you give any suggestion to display all datas marked in red in a msgbox

Comment: See the **Edit 2** if this is what you are looking for. *Off topic : I didn't know that the one array item can store multiple rows and columns. Thank you for this experience. ;)*

Comment: +2 Hey works great. Exactly what i wanted. Thanks mate.

Comment: BTW.. `For y = 1 To 6
            If y = 1 Then
                strMessage = dar(j3)(1, y)
            Else
                strMessage = strMessage & " || " & dar(j3)(1, y)
            End If
        Next y

        j3 = j3 + 1`                   What does this statement Mean. I understand What it does but not the each statement

Comment: You're welcome. To explain the code...The first loop `If y=1 then...`, ` strMessage` is stored as such. The next values are appended to previous `strMessage` with the vizual delimiter ` || ` (you can change the delimiter to whatever you like). If you put it into watch or open the locals window while running the code, you can see step by step how it changes. As for the **array referencing** `dar(j3)(1, y)` the first parenthesis is array item index, the next is (row,column) index inside this array item (in our case it's always 1 row and multiple columns - y). In general : Array(item)(row,column)

Answer (score 1):

Please  Check this line

`Range("b" & i3, "f" & i3).Value`. it nothing fetch any value.
If you Test this line immediate window it shows an error. Please fix 
if you want to store the two values mean 2d- array, Declare the 2D array.

Comment: Yes i tested it with the above suggestion i was able to fix this issue. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: I used watch it is displaying the data. Did you try using Watch for dar(j3) under the loop